# Tengo este problema: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable ¿alguna solucion?

Tags: php

Hola acabo de instalar la plataforma LMS CLAROLINE y cuando voy a los cursos creados me sale el erro siguiente. he estado viendo por todos lados pero no encuentro solucion, soy muy nuevo en esto de php alguien me podria dar una ayuda porfa, ya que esta plataforma la queremos usar el centro de ensñanza de adultos  (CENS). desde ya muchas gracias
Courses in this category
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

---

mucho no se de codigo php, pero cuando entro a la sección de loscursos y me tendría que mostrar el listado de cursos, (pero creo que este seria la parte del codigo).

al principio del codigo de la pagina sale esto,

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------
    Display course list
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

```
case DISPLAY_COURSE_TREE :
{
    //  Display Title
    if ( $fromAdmin == 'class' )
    {
        $mainTitle = get_lang('Enrol class');
        $subTitle = $classinfo['name'];
    }
    else
    {
        $mainTitle = get_lang('User\'s course') ;
        $subTitle = $userInfo['firstname'] . ' ' . $userInfo['lastname'];
    }

    $cmdList = array();

    /*
     * When you enroll another user and if you are platform admin, 
     * give the possibility to enroll him as a student or as a teacher
     */
    if ($fromAdmin == 'usercourse' && claro_is_platform_admin())
    {
        // Rewrite the "asTeacher" URL parameter only for this button action
        if ($asTeacher)
        {
            $cmdList[] = array(
                'img' => 'user',
                'name' => get_lang('Enrol as student'),
                'url' => Url::buildUrl($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?cmd=rqReg', 
                    array_merge($urlParamList, array('asTeacher' => 'false')), 
                    null)->toUrl(),
            );
        }
        else
        {
            $cmdList[] = array(
                'img' => 'manager',
                'name' => get_lang('Enrol as teacher'),
                'url' => Url::buildUrl($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?cmd=rqReg', 
                    array_merge($urlParamList, array('asTeacher' => 'true')), 
                    null)->toUrl(),
            );
        }
    }

    // Display the title
    $out .= claro_html_tool_title(array(
        'mainTitle' =>  $mainTitle, 
        'subTitle' => $subTitle), 
        null, 
        $cmdList);

    // Display dialogbox and backlink
    $out .= $dialogBox->render();

    $out .= $categoryBrowser->getTemplate()->render()
          . $searchBox->render();
}
break;
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea de código donde ta da el error? Estás aplicando `count` sobre algo que no se puede contar. Si muestras el contexto del error podemos decirte cómo corregirlo.

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a la versión de `php` que haz utilizado para instalar el LMS. Revisa los requerimientos técnicos de la versión que necesitas instalar e instala una versión de php dentro del rango que se especifica.

Comment: cesar probe todas las versiones de php de mi servidor, y solo tengo ese problema en la pagina donde lista mis cursos, ya que toda la pagina anda bien.

Comment: Puedes especificar que versión de php tienes y que versión del lms estás instalando?